# fprintf printing garbage to txt file

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with strings and c.

I'm trying to do something very simple: converting an int into a string and printing it into a txt file in the following fashion.

```
const char * test_string() {
    char s[5];
    int num = 123;
    sprintf(s, "%d", num);
    return s;
}

int save() {
    FILE *fh = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    const char * text = test_string();
    fprintf(fh, "%s", text);
    fclose(fh);
}
```

Yet, for this simple task, I'm getting the following result:

```
Üþ(
```

I'd like some assistance with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Returning the address of a local variable from a function has undefined behaviour, because the variable is no longer alive after the function has returned.

Comment: @KerrekSB: We should add a dup to this question to the info-page. That question is asked every few days.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently C is more complex than it seems.

Comment: @miroki123: If you have a good C book and read it **carefully**, it is actually not.

Comment: You could also look at [Difference between dangling pointer and memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132798/difference-between-dangling-pointer-and-memory-leak)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` is a local variable in `test_string`, so it is destroyed when `test_string` returns. Then, you try to print the value of a variable that no longer exists.

Comment: The mess it prints is a string interpretation of whatever happens to have filled that space in the meantime.