# Clarification about C++ delete and memory leaks

Tags: c++

To my understanding, the C++ compiler automatically tries to delete objects that go out of scope. However, within [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132798/difference-between-dangling-pointer-and-memory-leak) which documents a dangling pointer situation, there is a `char` array gets automatically cleared but there was no `delete` operation:

```
char *func()
{
   char str[10];
   strcpy(str, "Hello!");
   return str; 
}
```

This apparently returns a dangling pointer because the memory would have been freed after the scope. But how can this be, if I didn't specify `delete`? To my point, [this website](https://study.com/academy/lesson/memory-leaks-in-c-programming.html) shows what I thought would happen in a similar situation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void oil_leak() {
  //allocate 8 bytes from heap
  double *pointer = new double(32.54);
}
int main() {
  oil_leak();
}
```

Namely, allocated memory for the pointer is not freed after the scope, leading to a memory leak.

Comment: Look up the distinction between stack and heap allocated variables.

Comment: A destructor can be written to perform a deletion but it's not required. And that possibilty certainly doesn't mean that the compiler will autmatically delete anything.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The compiler doesn't automatically apply the `delete` operator to anything - in rough terms, everything allocated with operator `new` must be manually released using the corresponding operator `delete`. Objects with automatic storage duration - like `str` in your `func()` automatically cease to exist when code leaves their enclosing scope, so `func()` return a dangling reference.  But the lifetime of variables with automatic storage duration has nothing to do with the compiler deleting anything.

Comment: By the way, your first code snippet has **undefined behavior** if returned data is used by the caller .

Answer (score 5):

`To my understanding, the C++ compiler automatically tries to delete objects that go out of scope.` That is incorrect, you are confusing deletion with destruction. Destruction is automatic, deletion is not.

In the case you quote the array `str` is destroyed and therefore there is a dangling pointer. Deletion has no part in this code because there is no allocation. Allocation happens when you use `new`, and it's allocated memory that needs to be deleted.

Your 'similar situation' is actually completely different. In fact it's a good illustration of the difference. The pointer `pointer` is destroyed (like all block scoped variables) but that does not mean that the memory it is pointing to will be deleted. Only a call to `delete` would do that.

Answer (score 4):

You have a misunderstanding of how data on the stack works. When you do this:

```
void oil_leak() {
    char str[10];
}
```

There is no "new" being called. The compiler makes room on the stack. When the function returns, the stack pointer is returned to the original value, "freeing" the memory. But it isn't using new/delete, and it's a mistake to think of it that way.

When you do this:

```
char * cPtr = new char[20];
```

You are actually "allocating" two sections of data. On the local stack, you're making a pointer (8 bytes). And on the heap, you're allocating 20 more bytes.

If you then exit without `delete [] cPtr`, you never free those 20 bytes. But the stack pointer goes back to its original value (your pointer falls out of scope), so you're not leaking that data.

To get to your original question:

```
char str[10];
return str;
```

This is a problem because you return a pointer into space that is no longer going to be allocated. It's now random space, and anything could happen to it. It's not a memory leak, but it's bad code.

Answer (score 2):

There's an important difference between "destroy" and "delete" here. The C++ language guarantees many objects are automatically destroyed at a certain point, ending the object's "lifetime". The deletion done by a `delete ptr` or `delete[] ptr` expression is different, and is never done automatically by the language.

"Destroy" here just means to end an object's lifetime, plus do automatic cleanup for class types (which includes types defined with `class`, `struct`, or `union`):

- Destroying an object with class type invokes the class destructor.
- Destroying a raw array of objects with class type, or array of array of class objects, etc., invokes the class destructor for each class object.
- "Destroying" any other type, like an `int` or `std::string*` object, does nothing beyond ending the object lifetime.

Every C++ object needs memory storage(1), which is valid for part of the program execution. An object also has one of four kinds of "storage duration" affecting the validity of that memory and the lifetime of the object:

- Automatic storage duration is used for most function-local variables (not marked `extern` or `static`). The language handles providing memory for the object for at least its lifetime. The object is associated with a `{`compound statement`}`. The object is initialized when execution reaches the definition statement, and is destroyed when execution leaves the compound statement, whether by `return`, `break`, `continue`, `throw`, or even `goto`.
- Static storage duration is used for variables whose lifetime goes up until (nearly) the end of the program. This includes global variables, other namespace scope variables, `static` class data members, and function-local variables defined `static`. The language handles providing memory valid for the entire program execution. The object is destroyed when the program exits normally, e.g. by `std::exit` or by returning from `main`.
- Thread storage duration is used for variables declared `static thread_local`. This acts very much like static storage duration, but for a thread instead of for the program.
- Dynamic storage duration is used for objects created by a `new` expression. Memory is allocated and the object is initialized when the `new` is evaluated. The object is destroyed and the memory is deallocated only when (and if) a correct `delete` expression is evaluated.

The point here is that for an object with dynamic storage duration, the program is entirely responsible for when the object's lifetime will end and its memory deallocated. For any other object, the C++ language is responsible for both of these things, and there's little a program can do about that.
So the rule to avoid memory leaks for dynamic storage duration is "one `new` evaluated, one `delete` evaluated". (There are other things to watch out for with `new` and `delete` to keep everything valid. I won't get into the other rules here.)

In your first example `func`, `str` has automatic storage duration. So no `delete` expression is needed, and inserting one would not be valid since the pointer did not come from a `new` expression. So the lifetime of `str` ends at the `return`, and using the returned pointer value won't be valid.

In your second example `oil_leak`, the `new` expression allocates memory for and initializes an unnamed object of type `double` with dynamic storage duration. Then `pointer` is initialized with a pointer to that object. When `oil_leak` returns, the variable `pointer` is destroyed, but destroying a raw pointer variable does nothing to the object it points at. The object of type `double` and its memory still exist. But since the program no longer has any pointers to that object or ways to get such a pointer value, it's not possible to ever do a `delete` to free up that memory.

Correctly using `new` and `delete` can be pretty tricky. Luckily, they are almost never needed in modern C++. The basic uses of dynamic storage can nearly always be covered by `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and the container classes like `std::vector`, `std::string`, etc. Fancier uses of "placement `new`" techniques (mixing up the relationships between the memory and lifetime of objects) can nearly always be covered by `std::optional` and `std::variant`. All of these typically use `new` and `delete` in their own implementations, but wrap around those details in a way which is easier to use and avoids many ways of accidentally getting it wrong.

Footnote 1: A C++ variable might end up not using any physical memory bytes at all in an executed program, if the compiler can optimize that memory away. But the compiler needs to act "as if" it did occupy memory if there's any way the program could tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet, `str` is an example of a stack-allocated variable. Its lifetime is limited to the scope it lives in.

```
char *func()
{
   char str[10];
   strcpy(str, "Hello!");
   return str; 
} // -> str object is destructed here, cannot be referenced after this point
```

If you want to use this variable beyond this scope, you will need to copy the object by value (clone). If it were allocated on the heap (using `operator new`), its lifetime can persist beyond this scope, but you become responsible for managing it.

```
void oil_leak() {
  double *pointer = new double(32.54);
} // -> obj persists in memory beyond this scope, until you delete it,
```

It's easy to get manually memory management wrong. So in modern C++, we use smart-pointers to manage allocated resources and use the [`RAII`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) technique. This allows us to controls resources (like heap-allocated memory) whilst the objects/smart-pointers behaving like a stack-allocated variable, i.e. when it goes out of scope,  the object is destructed and it's [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) deletes the managed resource.